# What does "define" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody rewrite this sentence for me, please?
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/define?q=define

> *"Success in anchoring inflation in the 1980s and 1990s **defined** central banking throughout the developed world."*

([Source](http://in.reuters.com/article/us-usa-fed-inflation-analysis-idINKBN19630N))

Comment: I think it means controlling the inflation rate was the first priority of the central banking systems during the period. To the point that the author claims it defined and shaped the cores of the central banking systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, *to define* means (1.2) [to make up or establish the character or essence of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/define).